# Return all elements in a wpf Grid.Column

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

Is it possible to find an iterate through all UI elements present in a wpf `Grid` column?

EG

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" Name="basicColumn"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="65*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

foreach (UIElement elem in basicColumn.Elements)
{
    //do something
}
```

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

Comment: Changed post to make the question clearer

Answer (score 3):

In WPF controls/`UIElement`s are in `Grid` and not in Column/Rows. So your should iterate over `Grid.Children`

```
int index = mygrid.ColumnDefinitions.IndexOf(basicColumn);

foreach (UIElement uie in mygrid.Children)
{
    if(Grid.GetColumn(uie) == index)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: So I would have to iterate through every item in Grid.Children and check its Column value against the one I want?

Comment: @user589195: Check my edited answer. It finds UIElement by column-name.